# What determines the spin of fields in gauge field theories?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I understand that gauge bosons transform as the adjoint of their respective symmetry groups, but what determines the spin of the field? Can you have some gauge group where the adjoint is spin zero?

Comment: I think there is a little bit of ambiguity in the question. When you say "spin", (1) do you talk about which representation the gauge field transforms in under gauge transformations? Or (2), are you talking about how it transforms under space-time symmetries? If (1): the word "spin" is usually mainly used for $SU(2)$ so the first question is not really clear. If I interpret "spin zero" in your second question as "trivial representation", then the answer is any compact abelian group such as $U(1)$ (the adjoint rep. is not the trivial rep. otherwise. dim Adjoint rep = dim group).

Comment: If (2): in this case your first sentence only makes sense for spin-1 fields and the spin of the gauge boson does not depend on the gauge group. Maybe your question is more in the direction of: "can we have gauge theories with gauge fields with other spins than 1?". I am very likely misunderstanding your questions.

Comment: With $N= 2$ supersymmetry, you may have a vector multiplet with particles of spin $1, 1/2,0$ which belong to the adjoint representation of the gauge group.

Comment: @Trimok in that case, the two spin $1/2$'s and the spin $0$ are essentially massless matter fields in the adjoint representations, and the gauge field is purely spin $1$ right? The gauge group does not decide the spin of that field and the masslessness of the spin $1/2$ and $0$ fields does not introduce new gauge symmetries. By purely looking at representation theory of the Poincare group, isn't it clear that gauge symmetries are only occurring in the massless limit for spin $s\geq 1$? I am misunderstanding something here or maybe the question?

Comment: @Heidar : I have a little doubt about spin $0$ to be a matter field, otherwise I agree with you remarks.

Comment: @SUSYquest : You have to differntiate space-time symmetries and their representations (roughly spin), and internal "gauge" symmetries. The global symmetry is the product of the space-time symmetry (Poincaré  symmetry) and the internal symmetry. Without supersymmetry, gauge bosons are in the adjoint representation of the internal symmetry, and matter particles are in the fundamental representation of this internal symmetry.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity in my question. I **did** mean spin as the IR of Poincaré symmetry, which, @Heidar, I think corresponds to your interpretation number (2).

Comment: @Heidar would you consider editing my question to make it more sensible? I think you have an understanding of what I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already mentioned in comments, the question is ambiguous. In any case 'spin' is the same as (irreducible) representation of some group, i.e. specifying spin is equivalent to giving the lowest weight of some group or its Lie algebra. Now, there are at least three different types of spin one can think about after your question.

1) Spin refers to the tensor type of the field your work with. Here tensor means tensor of the Lorentz grop $SO(d-1,1)$ if we are in dimension $d$. Then $\phi(x)$ has spin zero, the Yang-Mills field, $A_\mu$, has spin one (and we ignore all other types of indices it can carry). Graviton, $g_{\mu\nu}$, has spin two.

2) Spin refers to the physical degrees of freedom, i.e. to the solution space of the field equations. The relevant group in this context is the Wigner little group, (see, e.g. the second chapter of Weinberg's Quantum field theory). For massive fields Wigner's little group is $SO(d-1)$ and it is $SO(d-2)$ for massless. To determine spin one has to solve linearized equations of motion. Then $A_\mu$ turns out to carry spin one, the number of spin one fields we have is given by the dimension of adjoint, i.e. just the number of $A_\mu(x)$'s in $A^a_\mu T_a$. In this context on needs background, Minkowski space in our case, that has enough symmetries at least assymptotically.

3) Spin refers to the representation of the gauge group. It does not necessarily have to be the adjoint. (This usage of spin is extremely misleading)

Comment: Sorry, but Your answer is not clear and sometimes wrong:   For each $d$, a massless $A_\mu$ corresponds to  the fundamental representation of $SO(d-2)$, and a massless $g_{\mu\nu}$ corresponds to the symmetric traceless representation of $SO(d-2)$.  This has - a priori - nothing to do with the representation of the gauge group.

Comment: Exactly, as I described, there are at least three different usages of spin, and some of them have nothing to do with gauge groups. There is nothing wrong about the answer, but the question is not 100% clear. I have tried to answer "what determines the spin of the field" part.

Comment: Spin, in the canonical usage of this term, a priori - has nothing to do with the representation of the gauge group :)

Comment: Yes, when I said spin zero, I do mean a Lorentz-invariant (scalar) quantity and not Lorentz-covariant. And, I would like to know specifically if you can have a spin-zero gauge boson.

Comment: You begin with $A_\mu^a T_a$. There are no scalars by definition, they are all vectors. Unless you do something very very strange there is no way to get scalar. Consider Higgs mechanism, Kaluza-Klein reduction etc. as various ways to get scalars not far from the Yang-Mills field :)